# Discord.js Suggestion Channel Code Not Working

Tags: discord.js

```
const emojiChannelID = '762366483622789170';
client.on('ready', async () => {
  try {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(emojiChannelID);
    if (!channel) return console.error('Invalid ID or missing channel.');

    const messages = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 });

    for (const [id, message] of messages) {
      await message.react('<yes:762371315239485480>');
      await message.react('<no:762371418867761172>');
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Using latest, or at least close to latest version of Discord.js

No errors are shown, but in the channel it doesn't react on the messages

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will only get the last 100 messages **when the bot is ready**. If you would like to react to messages as they come in, you need to use the `client.on("message")` event which will be fired every time a message is sent. Here's an example.

```js
client.on("message", async(msg)=>{
   try {
      if(msg.channel.id!=="762366483622789170") return; // do not run outside suggestions channel
      await msg.react("762371315239485480"); // react with yes
      await msg.react("762371418867761172"); // react with no
   } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
   }
}
```

Comment: Custom emojis not working still, I've tried multiple ways to fix it but none work.